# Core Plot shows wrong date on x-Axis

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, core-plot

I have an issue with showing a range of dates on x-axis. This range contains dates as timestamp values: 1398172101, 1398176156, 1398181026, 1398196536, etc. Below code shows how I try to format the date to be human-readable

```
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm dd/MM/yy"];
 CPTTimeFormatter *timeFormatter = [[CPTTimeFormatter alloc] initWithDateFormatter:dateFormatter];
 timeFormatter.referenceDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:0.0];
 x.labelFormatter = timeFormatter;
```

I'm not sure if I set right value for `timeFormatter.referenceDate`. I found a question on stackoverflow which describe same issue, but the right answer doesn't work for me. It tells to assing `[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:0.0]` to `timeFormatter.referenceDate`

Whats the mistake I did ? Thanks

Comment: What is the zero (0) point of the timestamps? You've set it to 1 January 1970.

Comment: @EricSkroch each of my timestamp value was generated using [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]

Comment: The Core Plot code looks ok. What is the problem? Do you get labels with the wrong format? Offset from the correct date and time?

Comment: The date is well formatted on labels. The issue is that the dates are wrong, like example: 03:00 03/01/70 . Look at the year: 2070, time and rest of the date are also wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the `xRange` of the plot space is set correctly. For example, to make a range enclosing the values listed in the question, do this:

```
NSTimeInterval minTime = 1398172101;
NSTimeInterval maxTime = 1398196536;
plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromDouble(minTime)
                                                length:CPTDecimalFromDouble(maxTime - minTime)];
```

Comment: You are right. xRange property had a wrong value. Your code is working perfectly. Thanks.